# Fastest way to show an element

Tags: jquery, html, css

I have a hidden `div` element,I can use many methods to show the hidden div like

```
1.  $(my_div).addClass('show');    (.show{display:block;})
2.  $(my_div).css('display','block');
3.  $(my_div).show();
```

I need to know which one is more faster?or suggest any other methods

Comment: the best method is the 3rd one

Comment: Is it an exam!? the method is simple, short and does what you need.

Comment: my jsperf - http://jsperf.com/fastest-way-of-showing-an-element

Answer (score 1):

`my_div.style.display  = 'block'` would be fastest, assuming it's a native DOM node as you're wrapping it with jQuery

Comment: Should note that this is nothing but a micro-optimization which doesn't really matter, as 99% of the overhead will be due to the reflow triggered by changing the element's `display` property.

Comment: @FabrícioMatté - Sure, in most cases it wouldn't matter, but the question was "what is faster", and native javascript is always faster.

Comment: Yeah your answer is right. I just noted that this kind of micro-optimization hardly ever makes any visible difference. I didn't downvote btw.